# jQuery positioning footer without element the jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am using jQuery to position the footer absolutely on pages where there isnt much content.

The problem I have noticed is that the footer loads in it's normally position and then visibily jumps to the bottom of the page when the jQuery adds the class. Is there anyway to get around this jump?

```
        /* Position footer bottom of all pages */
    positionFooter: function () {
        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        var content = jQuery("#content").height() + jQuery("#footer-wrapper").height();
        if (windowHeight > content){
            jQuery("#content").css("padding-bottom", jQuery("#footer-wrapper").height());
            jQuery("#footer-wrapper").addClass("fixed-bottom");
        }
    }
```

I am using window.load:

```
jQuery(window).load(function()
```

Comment: may be you can hide fotter by default and show by jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
positionFooter: function () 
        {
            var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            var content = jQuery("#content").height() + jQuery("#footer-wrapper").height();
            jQuery("#footer-wrapper").addClass("fixed-bottom");
            jQuery("#footer-wrapper").hide();
            if (windowHeight > content)
            {
                jQuery("#content").css("padding-bottom", jQuery("#footer-wrapper").height());
                jQuery("#footer-wrapper").show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty fix would be to give the `body { opacity: 0}` before the document loads, and then animate the opacity back up to 1 over a period of, say, 1 second. That way, the whole body will fade in after the footer has *already* jumped.

[simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzzLgty/)

This is how a lot of people deal with [Flashes Of Unstyled Content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) (or FOUC).

Edit: As Freeeeez pointed out below, using body as the animatee isn't necessary, but in my opinion the effect is pleasing :)

Comment: i think it would be better to set footer `opacity` to 0 instead of setting the whole body.

Comment: @Freeeeez Google's Polymer uses a full body fade-in by default to hide unresolved content. The effect is actually pretty nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you set it to `display:none` as default with a specific class. You could then use jQuery to remove the class after the document has finished loading with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hideMe').removeClass('hideMe');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the html, maybe you should use a css sticky footer
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

I've used this in a lot of websites and works just fine